# Altering a const std::string in C++

Tags: c++, string, copy, constants, std

I have a const std::string to which I want to append another string. But since it's constant, I can't alter it directly; I'll have to copy it to another string somehow.  How do I do this?

Comment: so you want to modify the string that you have? Or do you want it stored in a new std::string? What have you tried? What was wrong with `std::string newString = myString + otherString;`?

Comment: Thanks! I'm used to crazy C strings, C++ is much better

Answer (score 4):

You just have to create another string:

```
const std::string str = "Hello";
std::string other = str + ", world!";
```